# Can anyone recommend good Flex 4(.5) Mobile iOS/iPhone/iPad styled Components?

Tags: ios, mobile, mxml, flex-skins

Can anyone recommend good library with components or skins for existing components that would mimic iOS/iPad style for Flex 4.5 Mobile Application project please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure about components, but here is a mobile IOS theme: http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/06/ios-theme-for-flex-mobile-projects-proof-of-concept.html

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
http://code.google.com/p/flexpad/

Answer (score 0):

FlexPad is related to MAC/PC projects

for mobile application project better look on FlexPadMobile http://code.google.com/p/flexpadmobile/